# Finding the right PHP file to edit

Tags: php

This post follows research and another recent SO post. That question was along the lines of "Is there a way on any PHP site to identify the file that contains the html that you are viewing on a webpage?" Using, for example "inspect element" feature.

It appears not. Fine. Is there a conventional way around this? From research it seems it's a security issue so with PHP you cannot.

I can login to the host using Filezilla. I want to edit my main Navigation menu. I'd therefore like to search for something like Nav, Navigation, Main menu etc but there does not appear to be a search feature along those lines.

What do developers typically do here (I am very new to PHP). How does one typically identify a file to make edits when they are working on a site that they did not create?

Comment: I always just find something which is pretty unique in the HTML and search through the folder to find it. You would have to download the source, but you should do that either way because you are not going to edit code and test on a remote machine are you?

Comment: Well, developers typically develop in their own machine. Uploading files via FTP to test every single change is absolutely annoying. (And I hope you aren't developing directly on the live site.)

Comment: @PeeHaa and Alvaro ...umm.. I was! I guess I'll post a separate question too "How do you sync a wip site with live site. Thanks for the feedback though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help: go into the source and find beginning of the specific piece of HTML generated for your navigation. It might be (I'm not including the closing tag because that might be generated dynamically):

```
<nav id="main"
```

or

```
<ul class="navigation"
```

Get something like Sublime Text and drag the project folder into it. Then do Find -> Find in Files (Ctrl-Shift-F) and search for that snippet of HTML.

Hopefully you should find what you're looking for.